# How to find out if a given number/text is missing from index of a multi-index pandas dataframe?

Tags: pandas, python-3.x

I have a multi-index pandas dataframe as in below. What I want is to figure out if a particular level1 index is present given a particular level 0 index. To be clear, notice that for level 0 index "foo", level 1 index "two" is missing in the toy example below. So I want to find out all those level 0 indices, whether a given index (in this case "two") is missing or not. For this toy example, my result will be "foo". The pandas dataframe I have has over 40,000 entries.

```
INDEX            COL1
level0 level1       
first  second
bar    one       0.361041
       two       0.476720
baz    one       0.565781
       two       0.848519
foo    one       0.405524
qux    one       0.488229
       two       0.303862
```

Is there any way, other than, cycling through the dataframe in a for loop, I can achieve this?

Thanks for your comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this to identify the missing rows:

```
i=df.index.get_level_values(0).unique()
j=df.index.get_level_values(1).unique()
indx = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([i,j])
indx[df.reindex(indx).isna().squeeze()].tolist()
```

Thanks to @Alollz improvement:

```
indx=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([*df.index.levels])
indx[df.reindex(indx).isna().squeeze()].tolist()
```

Output:

```
[('foo', 'two')]
```